# Forcing SSL login, have to log in again from WP/BP-Admin Bar

Tags: login, admin-bar, ssl

I am forcing SSL login on a multisite install running BuddyPress, and after doing so I have to log in a second time when trying to access anywhere in the dashboard via the admin bar.

Comment: Maybe the admin bar links are HTTP?

Comment: Sorry, should have noted that they are, but they're generated dynamically (dashboard, new post, etc). How do I force those to be https?

Comment: How are you forcing the SSL login?

Comment: define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true); in wp-config

Comment: also using define( 'BP_USE_WP_ADMIN_BAR', true );